# Bash script, command - output to array, then print to file

Tags: bash, shell

I need advice on how to achieve this output:

```
myoutputfile.txt
    Tom Hagen 1892
    State: Canada
    Hank Moody 1555
    State: Cuba
    J.Lo 156
    State: France
```

output of mycommand:

```
/usr/bin/mycommand
        Tom Hagen
        1892
        Canada
        Hank Moody
        1555
        Cuba
        J.Lo
        156
        France
```

Im trying to achieve with this shell script:

```
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' :; names=( $(/usr/bin/mycommand) )
for name in ${names[@]}
do
#echo $name
echo ${name[0]} 
#echo ${name:0} 
done
```

Thanks

Comment: Please let us know if you really have Windows-style line endings, as `$'\r\n'` suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can always rely on the command to output groups of 3 lines, one option might be

```
/usr/bin/mycommand | 
  while read name;
        read year;
        read state; do
    echo "$name $year"
    echo "State: $state"
  done
```

An array isn't really necessary here.

One improvement could be to exit the loop if you don't get all three required lines:

```
while read name && read year && read state; do
    # Guaranteed that name, year, and state are all set
    ...
done
```

Comment: Great, thanks :)

what if $year is unique id number and every day would /usr/bin/mycommand  produce newer output. Its possible to echo only unique records based on id? So every other day would be only incremental echo to output file? Thanks

Comment: That's going from simple output reformatting to more complex state handling (specifically, reading the current output file to see what is already then and filtering the output of `mycommand` based on that). You're better off writing a dedicated program in that case (one not written in shell script).

Answer (score 2):

An easy one-liner (not tuned for performance):

```
/usr/bin/mycommand | xargs -d '\n' -L3 printf "%s %s\nState: %s\n"
```

It reads 3 lines at a time from the pipe and then passes them to a new instance of `printf` which is used to format the output.

If you have whitespace at the beginning (it looks like that in your example output), you may need to use something like this:

```
/usr/bin/mycommand | sed -e 's/^\s*//g' | xargs -d '\n' -L3 printf "%s %s\nState: %s\n"
```

Comment: Nicely done - by far the simplest solution; the only caveat is that `-d` is a nonstandard _GNU_ `xargs` extension (won't work on OSX, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=0
/usr/bin/mycommand | while read LINE
do

    if [ $COUNTER = 0 ]; then
        NAME="$LINE"
        COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))

    elif [ $COUNTER = 1 ]; then
        YEAR="$LINE"
        COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))

    elif [ $COUNTER = 2 ]; then
        STATE="$LINE"
        COUNTER=0

        echo "$NAME $YEAR"
        echo "State: $STATE"
    fi

done
```

Comment: Nice, but you could simplify incrementing the counter to the following single statement `(( COUNTER = (COUNTER + 1) % 3 ))` (similarly, you could use `(( COUNTER == 0 ))`, ... as the conditionals). Also, it's [better not use all-uppercase variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01), because they can conflict with environment variables and special shell variables. Finally, I suggest using `read -r` (so as not to interpret backslashes).

Comment: Thank you very much! I always look a way to improve my bash!

Answer (score 1):

- [chepner's pure `bash` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804610/45375) is simple and elegant, but slow with large input files (loops in `bash` are slow).
- [Michael Jaros' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805228/45375) is even simpler, *if* you have *GNU* `xargs` (verify with `xargs --version`), but also does not perform well with large input files (external utility `printf` is called once for every 3 input lines).

**If performance matters**, try the following **`awk` solution**:

```
/usr/bin/mycommand | awk '
 { ORS = (NR % 3 == 1 ? " " : "\n")
  gsub("^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]*\r?$", "") } 
 { print (NR % 3 == 0 ? "State: " : "") $0 }
' > myoutputfile.txt
```

- `NR % 3` returns the 0-based index of each input line within its respective group of consecutive 3 lines; returns `1` for the 1st line, `2` for the 2nd, and `0`(!) for the 3rd.
- `{ ORS = (NR % 3 == 1 ? " " : "\n")` determines `ORS`, the output-record separator, based on that index: a *space* for line 1, and a newline for lines 2 and 3; the space ensures that line 2 is appended to line 1 with a space when using `print`.
- `gsub("^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]*\r?$", "")` strips leading and trailing whitespace from the line - including, if present, a trailing `\r`, which your input seems to have.
- `{ print (NR % 3 == 0 ? "State: " : "") $0 }` prints the trimmed input line, prefixed by "State: " only for every *3rd* input line, and implicitly followed by `ORS` (due to use of `print`).

Comment: often, it's necessary to take a step back to really solve the problem, and not hack at a script.    i commend @mklement0 for that: really looking at  the problem.    the "i need a script" approach begs the question:  is this an exercise or a practical problem.   if an exercise, the question must be, "what's the object of the lesson?"   posters should be clear about this distinction.  the practical problem imposes real requirements.

Comment: Thanks, @MartyMcGowan. It certainly helps when OPs are clear about their objectives and constraints, but, over time, people with different needs and in different circumstances will stumble upon this page, so it's nice to have a range of answers, from quick and simple hack to robust solution; it would certainly also help if people who answer indicated where along this spectrum their answer falls, and what the limitations and pitfalls are.